# Beamer: Only some navigation symbols AND organize navigation symbols vertically

Tags: beamer

I'm creating a presentation with beamer and I would like to have the following:

1. navigation symbols vertically organized and
2. show not all navigation symbols, but only some

I can either achieve 1. or 2., but not both.

**Vertical navigation symbols:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}[vertical] 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{Test frame} 
foo   
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Only some navigation symbols, but horizontal:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\insertframenavigationsymbol \insertsectionnavigationsymbol \insertbackfindforwardnavigationsymbol} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test frame}
foo
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If I write `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}[vertical]{\insertframenavigationsymbol \insertsectionnavigationsymbol \insertbackfindforwardnavigationsymbol}`, I get an error message (`Missing \begin{document}`)

So what do I have to do to have, say only three navigation symbols vertically aligned?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will translate what is written here: http://mcclinews.free.fr/latex/introbeamer/elements_navigation.html

Both are not compatible. Then to choose your symbols to put vertically, you have to type this:

```
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}
{%
  \vbox{%
  \hbox{\insertslidenavigationsymbol}
  \hbox{\insertframenavigationsymbol}
  \hbox{\insertsubsectionnavigationsymbol}
  \hbox{\insertsectionnavigationsymbol}
  \hbox{\insertdocnavigationsymbol}
  \hbox{\insertbackfindforwardnavigationsymbol}}%
}
```

Comment: Ok, it seems somewhat strange to me that they are not compatible, but this "workaround" works perfectly well and achieves the desired effect.